# apr_socket_recv: Connection timed out (110)

Tags: linux, php, nginx, php-fpm, connection

I have nginx/php-fpm running but I am getting the following:

```
apr_socket_recv: Connection timed out (110)
```

This is a massive big box. 16 cores/24GB RAM

What do I need to tune to increase the allowed connections?

EDIT:

Just found this in dmesg

```
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
```

Looks like I need to up those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_generic_timeout = 12
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent = 12
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv = 12
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 2000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 12
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 12
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_last_ack = 12
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 10
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close = 8
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_max_retrans = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_unacknowledged = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_loose = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_max_retrans = 3
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout = 12
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream = 18
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_icmp_timeout = 8
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 1048576
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count = 7645
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets = 16384
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_checksum = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_log_invalid = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_expect_max = 256
```

Comment: I would just have increased `conntrack_max` and perhaps `conntrack_buckets`.